# Does $E(\sum e_i^2) = \sum E(y_i^2) - E(\sum \hat y_i^2)$ hold true?

Tags: statistics, proof-explanation, regression

This was posted as a practice proof for a regressions class. I've worked through it from the perspective of $SSE = SST - SSR$, but I cannot reduce to the given equation. There were other mistakes made in this practice homework, so it's possible this problem is missing something, but I don't want to pass off my inability to prove the equation on the practice problem's design.

We know that $E(\sum e_i^2) = E\sum (y_i - \hat y_i)^2$, but when factoring out the values, this side does not equal the right side of the equation. I thought to start from $SSE = SST - SSR$ and reduce that initial setup—$E\sum (y_i - \hat y_i)^2 = E\sum (y_i - \bar y)^2 - E\sum (\hat y_i - \bar y)^2$—but again I was unable to reduce the given values down to the initial equation given in the title. As I reduce it, there are leftover $2y_i \hat y_i$ and $2\hat y_i \bar y_i$, which I can't remove. I appreciate any insight into what I'm missing (or what the initial question is missing).

Comment: is this simple or multiple linear regression ?

Comment: @AhmadBazzi simple linear regression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In general it holds for simple and multi linear regression. Also, the expectations are not required.**

Well writing it in matrix form 
\begin{equation}
 Y = X\beta +\epsilon
\end{equation}
where $X$ is the $X \times 2$ matrix, then
\begin{equation}
 \sum e_i^2 = e^T e
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
 e = Y - \hat{Y}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
 \hat{Y} = (X^T X)^{-1}X^T Y \tag{1}
\end{equation}
So 
\begin{equation}
 \sum e_i^2 
 =
 (Y - \hat{Y})^T(Y - \hat{Y})
 =
 Y^TY - 2\hat{Y}^TY + \hat{Y}^T\hat{Y}
\end{equation}
It's easy to see that $\sum_i y_i = Y^TY$ and $\hat{Y}^T\hat{Y} = \sum_i \hat{y}_i$, but 
\begin{equation}
 \sum \hat{y}_iy_i = \hat{Y}^TY= ((X^TX)^{-1}X^TY)^T Y = Y^T X(X^TX)^{-1}\hat{Y}  \tag{2}
\end{equation}
But equation $(1)$ tells us that  $X^T Y = (X^T X)\hat{Y}$ or \begin{equation}
 Y^T X = \hat{Y}^T(X^T X) \tag{3}
\end{equation}
Replacing $(3)$ in $(2)$ you get
\begin{equation}
 \sum_i \hat{y}_iy_i =\hat{Y}^T(X^T X) (X^TX)^{-1}\hat{Y}
 =\hat{Y}^T \hat{Y} = \sum_i \hat{y}_i^2 \tag{4}
\end{equation}
Now, expanding $\sum e_i^2$, we get
\begin{equation}
 \sum_i e_i^2 = \sum y_i^2 - 2 \sum y_i\hat{y}_i + \sum \hat{y}_i^2 \tag{5}
\end{equation}
using equation $(4)$ in $(5)$, we get
\begin{equation}
 \sum_i e_i^2 = \sum y_i^2 - 2 \sum \hat{y}_i^2 + \sum \hat{y}_i^2
\end{equation}
that is

> \begin{equation}
>  \sum_i e_i^2 = \sum y_i^2 -  \sum \hat{y}_i^2 
> \end{equation}

Answer (score 2):

You are close.
I presume that from $SSE = SST - SSR$ you have
$$\sum_i e_i^2 = \sum_i (y_i - \bar{y})^2 - \sum_i (\hat{y}_i - \bar{y})^2
= \sum_i \hat{y}_i^2 - \sum_i y_i^2 - 2 \sum_i (y_i - \hat{y}_i) \bar{y},$$
and are wondering what to do with the extra term.

It turns out the last term is zero; you can prove this by looking at the "normal equations" (i.e. look at the derivation of the least squares coefficients) or by laboriously plugging in the definition of $\hat{y}_i$.

Note that the result holds even without the expectations.

[By the way, why do you have an index $i$ in $\bar{y}_i$? Isn't $\bar{y} := \frac{1}{n} \sum_i y_i$?]

Comment: Oops, the index is mistaken. I'll remove that from the post. I've not quite wrapped my head around how the last bit (in proof form) turns to zero, but conceptually it does make sense.

Answer (score 0):

To prove
$$E(\sum e_i^2) = \sum E(y_i^2) - E(\sum \hat y_i^2)$$
Just need to prove
$$\sum (y_i-\hat y_i)^2=\sum y_i^2-\sum\hat y_i^2$$
$$\sum y_i^2+\sum\hat y_i^2-2\sum y_i\hat y_i=\sum y_i^2-\sum\hat y_i^2$$
$$2\sum\hat y_i^2-2\sum y_i\hat y_i=0$$
Need to prove
$$\sum(y_i-\hat y_i)\hat y_i=0$$
$$\sum(y_i-\beta_0-\beta_1x_i)(\beta_0+\beta_1x_i)=0$$
$$\beta_0\sum(y_i-\beta_0-\beta_1x_i)+\beta_1\sum(y_i-\beta_0-\beta_1x_i)x_i=0$$
In Least squares regression, the sum of the squares of the errors is minimized.
$$
SSE=\displaystyle\sum\limits\left(e_i \right)^2= \sum\left(y_i - \hat{y_i} \right)^2= \sum\left(y_i -\beta_0- \beta_1x_i\right)^2
$$
Take the partial derivative of SSE with respect to $\beta_0$ and setting it to zero.
$$
\frac{\partial{SSE}}{\partial{\beta_0}} = \sum2\left(y_i - \beta_0 - \beta_1x_i\right)^1 (-1) = 0
$$
So
$$
\sum\left(y_i - \beta_0 - \beta_1x_i\right)^1 (-1) = 0
$$
Take the partial derivative of SSE with respect to $\beta_1$ and setting it to zero.
$$
\frac{\partial{SSE}}{\partial{\beta_1}} = \sum2\left(y_i - \beta_0 - \beta_1x_i\right)^1 (-x_i) = 0
$$
So
$$
\sum \left(y_i - \beta_0 - \beta_1x_i\right)^1 x_i = 0
$$
Hence
$$\beta_0\sum(y_i-\beta_0-\beta_1x_i)+\beta_1\sum(y_i-\beta_0-\beta_1x_i)x_i=0$$
$$E(\sum e_i^2) = \sum E(y_i^2) - E(\sum \hat y_i^2)$$